# Quill wont work

Tags: html, css, quill

I am trying to run Quill, but I can't figure out why is it not working.
It shows up in my textarea but it won't execute any command like bold text or italic text. But i can see toolbar.

I added this to my site:

```
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.5/quill.js"></script>

<script>
  var quill = new Quill('textarea', {
    modules: { toolbar: true },
    theme: 'snow'
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: No. there are no errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize Quill on div element. This works

HTML

```
<div id="editor"></div>
```

JS

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: { toolbar: true },
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

[Working pen](https://codepen.io/mnikolaus/pen/wyZeom)

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared is not showing any html element being passed to Quill element that is created.

You need it, like the official [docs](https://github.com/quilljs/quill#quickstart) suggests:

```
<div id="toolbar">
  <button class="ql-bold">Bold</button>
  <button class="ql-italic">Italic</button>
</div>

<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

And also need to make a reference to their ID when instantiating Quill, like:

```
var editor = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: { toolbar: '#toolbar' },
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

Here is a working fiddle:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YeMQaQ